# Using Scanner object String for Client/Server class Java

Tags: java, server, stream, client

I am having a hard time getting around The following.

I am attempting to send a message from a client in the form of a user input to a server class, this message is the in the form of the string. I want to use the message in the server class to perform some logic and based on that logic, have the server reply to the client .

I am able to make the program work using the scanner class by using integers to accomplish this. However, I cannot find out why it does not work with String variables.

This is my client Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class tripClient 
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
{

      String state,temp;


      // accept input
      Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
      // Socket, interphase to enable communication
      // with the server, simple socket or server
      // socket.
      // Client uses simple socket

      // IP of machine, port
      Socket s = new Socket("192.168.1.84",1234); // IP of machine, port

      // Use to get input stream, from the server
      Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());// input from the user


      System.out.println("Enter your desired state destination: ");
      // store number from user
      state = scr.nextLine();




      PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
      // Pass number onto server

      p.println(state); 


      //first task is to take a number, create the socket, pass number
      //  Next accept result from the server.

      //accepts an integer value, print result
      temp = sc1.nextLine();


      System.out.println(temp);
      // client is done 

   }
} 


This is my server Class:


import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.PrintStream;
public class tripServer
{

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
   {

      String stateS, tempS;


      // server accepts input from the client and processes
      // we also need a socket in the server, slightly different
      // Create a "server socket"

      ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(1234);

      // now we need a simple socket again;
      // server is ready to accept
      Socket ss = s1.accept(); 

      // Scanner

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(ss.getInputStream());

      stateS = sc.nextLine();



      tempS = stateS + " Hello";

      // We need to pass in this result back to the client
      // We again need the printStream Object

      // we will pass the temp thing to the client
      PrintStream p = new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
      p.println(tempS); 


   }

}
```

The interesting thing is that I can make something similar work with integer user inputs.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;


public class cli
{

   public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
   {
      int number, temp;
      String TEMP,NUMBER;
      // accept input
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      // Socket, interphase to enable communication
      // with the server, simple socket or server
      // socket.
      // Client uses simple socket

      // IP of machine, port
      Socket s = new Socket("192.168.1.84",1234); // IP of machine, port

      // Use to get input stream, from the server
      Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());// input from the user

      System.out.println("Please select from the following Destination Options:");
      System.out.println("\t(1) Arizona\n \t(2) New York\n \t(3) Utah\n \nTo select, enter the" +
         " Option Number");
      // store number from user
      number = sc.nextInt();
      //NUMBER = sc.nextLine();

      PrintStream p = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
      // Pass number onto server

      p.println(number); 
      //p.println(NUMBER);

      //first task is to take arr number, create the socket, pass number
      //  Next accept result from the server.

      //accepts an integer value, print result
      TEMP = sc1.nextLine(); 

      System.out.println(TEMP);
      // client is done     
   }
}   


import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class ser
{

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
   {

      int number, temp;
      String TEMP,NUMBER;
      // server accepts input from the client and processes
      // we also need a socket in the server, slightly different
      // Create a "server socket"

      ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(1234);

      // now we need a simple socket again;
      // server is ready to accept
      Socket ss = s1.accept(); 

      // Scanner

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(ss.getInputStream());

      number = sc.nextInt();
      //NUMBER = sc.nextLine();

      temp = number*2;
      //TEMP = NUMBER + "LOL";
      TEMP = "";
      if ( number == 1 )
      {
         TEMP = "You have Selected a Trip to Arizona for a price of $500\n";
      }
      else if ( number == 2)
      {
         TEMP = "You have Selected a Trip to New York for a price of $600\n";
      }
      else if ( number == 3)
      {
         TEMP = "You have Selected a Trip to Utah for a price of $300\n";
      }
      else 
      {
         TEMP = "Invalid Entry! Run program again!\n";
      }

      // We need to pass in this result back to the client
      // We again need the printStream Object

      // we will pass the temp thing to the client
      PrintStream p = new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
      p.println(TEMP);     
   }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried flushing?

Comment: Can you clarify, what exactly is not working? I just copied your code, changed the IP address from `192.168.1.84` to `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`, and everything ran as expected. It prompts me to enter a state, I enter the state, then it outputs the state with " Hello" appended on the end.

Comment: What exactly do you want. I think you are facing string to integer conversion problem.

Comment: For me the version of the program which uses strings does not work. What I get is the IOexception of empty line. This however does not happen when sending integer messages. I have attempted to flush with the nextLine() statement but it does not do anything. The problem seems to happen when the server sends the response back and the client attempts to store the value, it simply stores nothing. //accepts an integer value, print result temp = sc1.nextLine(); System.out.println(temp); // client is done